# QGIS - Export to .PDF loses partial XYZ Tile

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, xyz-tiles

When I create my print layout everything looks good, export to .pdf without errors. However when I open the .pdf in Adobe, or Avenza, part of the image (XYZ Tile) is gone.

I'm an absolute novice user.

[image: In QGIS Print Layout]
[image: In Adobe/Avenza]

Background: QGIS was working fine for the last few months until the last two maps I've tried to export. I am currently running the latest release. I restarted the program, relinked my XYZ tiles, but the problem persists.

Comment: This used to be a common occurence for me. Has not happened for over a year, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score -1):

Try option:

**Project -> Import/Export -> Export map as Image**

I would rather try with .png first and see what happens.